# Menu Items Appear on Two Lines Instead of One in Joomla

Tags: menu, joomla3.0

I added a new menu item to my joomla menu but now it appears on a second line instead of having all six of my menu items on a single horizontal line which makes my menu too thick vertically. How do I get them all on one line? Do I need to change the width of the menu?

[Picture of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbnh1.jpg)

[Picture of Title Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sANLv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: Reduce Menu Font Size and Padding**

I'd need a link to the website to be sure but it looks like you are using the RocketTheme Anacron template.

If so, you can create a custom CSS file at `/public_html/templates/rt_anacron/css/rt_anacron-custom.css` if one doesn't exist already and add the following code which adjusts the font sizes and padding to reduce the menu width on narrower screen widths:

```
/* Menu - Adjust for Screen Widths */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {font-size: 15px;}
  .gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {padding: 0 10px;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {font-size: 11px;}
  .gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {padding: 0 9px;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {font-size: 9px;}
  .gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {padding: 0 5px;}
}
```

You may need to adjust the font size and padding numbers to suit.

**Edit: Add additional options**

I now see you have a hidden logo and the menu in the header area with equal width (50% each).

**Option 2: Disable Logo in Header**

If you don't want the logo in the header, you can disable it in the template settings at `Extensions -> Template -> Anacron - Default -> Style`:

[image: Disable Anacron Logo]

**Option 3: Amend Layout so menu can use more than 50% of the width of the template**

If you want to keep the logo, you can amend the ratio between header elements at at `Extensions -> Template -> Anacron - Default -> Layouts` to provide enough room to keep your menu in one line:

[image]

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much I appreciate it

Comment: I have added some simpler options to fix the issue.

Comment: Wow great job. Thanks a lot that first option worked perfectly. I really appreciate it. Btw since you seem to know a lot about joomla  I was wondering you could please help me with a second separate issue I'm having adding a decorative title header to articles (Basically the title appears within a blue banner across the top of each article). I'm updating a website and I'm new to joomla so I'm not quite sure how these title banners were added to each of the article because they don't appear anywhere when I try to edit the article. I can send u a picture of what i mean if u would like

Comment: I added a picture of it to my original question at the top called "picture of title banner"

Comment: It may be hard to see but basically the title is inside a light blue banner and I was wondering how to recreate that in other articles

Comment: Hi @Deek, it's best to post a new question separately as you have done at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37554645/1983389