# Jommla 3 Header Title Bar

Tags: header, joomla3.0, titlebar

Does anybody know how to add a header "Title Bar" in joomla 3 for where the title should go for an article? I have attached a picture of what I'm looking for. Thanks

[Title Bar Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAmUq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you also can add for example a single line, we have a feature for **Custom Page Heading** on each Menu Item.

[image]

If you have for example a menu item type Category Blog, this will works for the entire section, same thing for menu item type Single Article and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the titles are being added by a module or modules in the `top-a` module position or similar.

Modules are found in the back-end of Joomla at `Extensions -> Modules`.

If these are implemented as separate modules for each page, you can duplicate an existing module and modify to suit including assigning the module to the appropriate page under the "Menu Assignment" tab.

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly and I was able to add the titles. Hey I can't thank you enough you've been a life safer. That website was due today and I was starting to freak out lol. Thanks again really appreciate it